# Problem with plugin in zend framework

Tags: zend-framework

I have created one plugin that is reside in application/controllers/plugin/view.php and below is its content

```
class Application_Controller_Plugin_View extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
    public function dispatchLoopStartup(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
    {
        $frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
        $view = $frontController->getParam('bootstrap')->getResource('view'); 
        echo 'erace';
        exit;
        $view->doctype('XHTML1_STRICT');

        $baseUrl = $request->getBaseUrl();
        if (defined('RUNNING_FROM_ROOT')) {
            $baseUrl .= '/public'; 
            $frontController->setBaseUrl($baseUrl); 
        }
      /*  $view->headLink()->appendStylesheet($baseUrl . '/css/main.css');
        $view->headLink()->appendStylesheet($baseUrl . '/css/screen.css', 'screen');
        $view->headLink()->appendStylesheet($baseUrl . '/css/print.css', 'print');*/
    }   
}
```

Then I have registered this plugin in bootstrap as follow :

```
protected function _initLayoutHelper()
    {

        $front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
        $front->registerPlugin(new Application_Controller_Plugin_View());       

    }
```

but its give me an error like

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Class 'Application_Controller_Plugin_View' not found in C:\wamp\www\saet_new\application\Bootstrap.php on line 42
```

Please help me.

Comment: Any specific reason you are using a plugin for this rather than a custom view application resource (or even just configuring the standard view application resource with params set in application.ini)?

Answer (score 2):

Is the plugin here:

library/application/controller/plugin/view.php

?

Custom code belongs in the library folder in my opinion, and that path is already defined in index.php

I register my namespaces in the bootstrap as follows:

```
$autoLoader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
$autoLoader->registerNamespace('Custom_');
```

Then library code can be put in the folder library/custom

Comment: yes my plugins path is library/application/controllers/plugin/view.php

Comment: Try changing application to something else e.g. custom so the path is library/custom/controllers/plugin/view.php and the class name is Custom_Controllers_Plugin_View also make sure that includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library" is set in the .ini file

Comment: I have changed directory too but still getting same error? any idea sir.

Comment: Curious, out of interest do you have any other plugins that work or is the first and only one? And can you autoload other classes in your library? You could also try registering the plugin in the .ini file instead of bootstrap resources.frontController.plugins.view = "Application_Controller_Plugin_View" for example, not that it should make a difference

Comment: It is worked now. I just added following line autoloadernamespaces.custom = "Custom_" in application.ini.

Comment: Yup that will do it, I thought it could be your autoloader that's the problem, I have this setup in my bootstrap - see edit

Answer (score 1):

I think it's caused because you are calling `Default_Application_Controller_Plugin_View` and you're plugin is `Application_Controller_Plugin_View`.

Are you using modules at all? that would explain why the Default_ would be there, although I believe the prefix isn't required unlesss `prefixDefaultModule` is set.